# i cant allocate an array of struct in c

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

```
row->cell=(CSV_CELL *) malloc(sizeof(CSV_CELL)*clms);
for(i=0;i<clms;i++)
{
    printf("size=(%d)\n",sizeof(row->cell[i]));
    printf("(%s)(%p)(%d)\n",tmp,&(row->cell[i]),*pty[i]);
}
```

the result is `size=16` and `clms=3`
when `i=0` the result of the second print is

```
(1)(006C0EA8)(0)
```

but when accessing the second element `i=1` the program crashed

the struct

```
typedef union
{
    int i;
    double d;
    char * s;
} CELL_VAL;

//the cells
typedef struct
{
    int type;
    CELL_VAL val;
}CSV_CELL;
```

Comment: The problem is more likely to be with `pty[i]`. You're not accessing the contents of the struct.

Comment: Post  type definition that has member `.cell`.  `CSV_CELL` is the wrong type in `row->cell=(CSV_CELL *) malloc(sizeof(CSV_CELL)*clms);`  Better to use `row->cell=malloc(sizeof *(row->cell) * clms);`

Comment: ohhh, yes i used `pty[0][i]` and it's works now,thanks